# Draw two or more images vertically in a single canvas

Tags: javascript, html

```
var base_image = new Image();
base_image.src = 'https://......jpg'; 
var can = document.getElementById("pai");
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
base_image.onload = function() {
    can.style.width = base_image.width;
    can.style.height = base_image.height;
          var imgWidth= base_image.width;
        var imgHeight=base_image.height;
        ctx.canvas.width= imgWidth;
        ctx.canvas.height= imgHeight;
        ctx.drawImage(base_image,0,0,imgWidth,imgHeight);
```

[manga like i reincarnated as a legendary surgeon](https://mangareadhere.xyz/2022/06/09/7-manga-like-i-reincarnated-as-a-legendary-surgeon/)

I am using above code to draw a image on canvas is there any way so I could draw 2 or more images vertically, thanks

Comment: By vertically do you mean one image at the top and the next image starting just below it?

Comment: Yes next images should start below the first image and third image below second image and so on..@AHaworth

Comment: What do you want to do about the sizing of the images. At the moment the canvas dimensions are set to accommodate the width and height of the image. If there are several what dimensions should they take?

Comment: @AHaworth don't care about it i just want several images to be drawn vertically on canvas

Comment: You'll have to decide what sort of width you want (then you can draw the images with their correct aspect ratios if you have a fixed width). How about making the width 100vw?

Comment: I can have a fixed width and height but I only lack on knowledge on how to draw two images on canvas @AHaworth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in general if you want to draw a bunch of images in a guaranteed order, you can try using a stack/array to store the images and then draw them in a loop!

The order of drawing will determine the order in which they're displayed.

Here's how I recommend you setup your code so that you load all the images you need first before you start drawing:

```
// Counter to keep track of how many images have loaded so far.
let imagesReady = 0;

// Array of image urls/srcs that you can easily update.
const imageSrcs = ['https://acnhcdn.com/latest/FtrIcon/FtrMarioRoundB.png', 'https://acnhcdn.com/latest/FtrIcon/FtrMarioSquareA.png'];

// Construct a new array with image objects
const images = imageSrcs.map((src) => {
  const image = new Image();
  image.src = src;
  
  // Increment our `imagesReady` counter once this image loads.
  image.onload = () => {
    imagesReady++;

    if (imagesReady >= imageSrcs.length) {
      // Trigger the image draw
      drawImages();
    }
  }
  return image;
});

const can = document.getElementById("pai");
const ctx = can.getContext('2d');

function drawImages() {
  // Set the canvas height to the sum of all image heights
  can.height = images.reduce((previousValue, image) => previousValue + image.height, 0);

  let lastImage = null;
  let lastImageY = 0;

  // We store the last image data above so that
  // we know what is the next Y to start drawing at.
  for (const image of images) {
    lastImageY = lastImage ? lastImageY + lastImage.height : 0;
    lastImage = image;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, lastImageY, image.width, image.height);
    ctx.restore();
  }
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sa509jbz/4/)

Note: Typically, when you have a canvas, you may tend to wrap it in a `setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame` loop so that you keep updating the canvas at, say, 30 or 60 frames per second (for example, if you're making an interactive canvas screen where positions/drawings change or you're making a game).

In that scenario, the above technique is a very simple/basic way of actually setting up a loading bar so that you can load all your assets first (until `imagesReady === imageSrcs.length`)

You could show a loading bar or loading message for a better user experience.